# Mysql group by overriding existing data in a query

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, left-join

I'm trying to do a group by of a shared column in 3 tables. But when I do a group by it overwrites my records of the unique data that I want. Below is my query of before doing a group by and after doing it. I'm trying to keep the *data* intact and not override it.

```
select wd.nid, 
       wd.sid, 
       ws.confirmed, 
       wc.form_key, 
       wd.data 
from webform_submitted_data wd 
left join webform_submissions ws on ws.sid = wd.sid 
left join webform_component wc on wc.cid = wd.cid 
where wd.nid = 31 
limit 25;

nid     sid     confi   type    data
31      9       1       email   at@gmail.com
31      10      1       email   at@gmail.com
31      12      0       email   sdf@gmail.com
31      13      0       email   at@gmail.com
31      14      1       email   at@gmail.com
31      15      1       email   at@gmail.com
31      8       1       pin     310438
31      9       1       pin     2893
31      10      1       pin     3424243
31      12      0       pin     32398
31      13      0       pin     3473939483
31      14      1       pin     177310438333
31      15      1       pin     34323
31      8       1       this    at@gmail.com
31      9       1       this    at@gmail.com
31      10      1       this    at@gmail.com
31      12      0       this    asdf@gmail.com
31      13      0       this    at@gmail.com
31      14      1       this    at@gmail.com
31      15      1       this    at@gmail.com
31      8       1       adddress_action 9110438
31      9       1       adddress_action 92893
31      10      1       adddress_action 233424243
31      12      0       adddress_action 922398
```

When I try to do a **group by sid** I get the following output:

```
31      8       1       email   at@gmail.com
31      9       1       email   at@gmail.com
31      10      1       email   at@gmail.com
31      12      0       email   asdf@gmail.com
31      13      0       email   at@gmail.com
31      14      1       email   at@gmail.com
31      15      1       email   at@gmail.com
```

What am I doing wrong or am I suppose to use some other statement?

Comment: Do you really want to `group by` sid, resulting in just one row summarizing information for each sid, or do you want to `order by`sid, showing rows for each value of `sid` grouped together`?

Comment: The purpose of `GROUP BY` is to merge all the rows with the same value of those columns into a single row. It's normally used together with aggregation functions like `COUNT()` or `SUM()`, which combine information from all the rows in the group.

Comment: What is your expected output